# java.io.IOException: Stream closed - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, postgresql, android-studio, java-io

Hey I am working with android studio and Postgresql, if anyone can help I will be grateful.

```html
 public class getlistAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String data="";
            String username="admin";
            String password="admin";
            URL url =null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection =null;
            publishProgress("doInBackground");
            try {
                url=  new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                data= Stream2String(in);
                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int datax = isw.read();
                while (datax != -1) {
                    char current = (char) datax;
                    datax = isw.read();
                    System.out.print(current);
                }
                publishProgress(data);


            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            //textView.setText(data);
            return data;
        }
```

Here it seems correct, but I dont get any information from my database. I get a blank page instead.

```html
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:287)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:350)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:179)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:128)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:114)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
        at org.hsbo.gierthhensen.coolesachenmitleaflet.List_laureat_Activity$getlistAsynctask.doInBackground(List_laureat_Activity.java:185)
        at org.hsbo.gierthhensen.coolesachenmitleaflet.List_laureat_Activity$getlistAsynctask.doInBackground(List_laureat_Activity.java:158)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

My database works perfectly with Postman and I get the responses i need using the same URL, but in the app it doesnt.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Stream2String` is doing, but it sounds like you're reading from the `InputStream` twice. `Stream2String` also closes the stream when it is done reading, then you cannot read from it anymore in the loop later on

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that I didnt close the stream, so I closed it after reading from it. And the problem was meanly in displaying the date, because I got the information from the server.